# Electron Angular App Errors when connecting to API

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, electron, electron-packager

I'm building my ionic/angular app as an electron app and when I run it and it loads I get the following error:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/whpacking/v1/getlocations' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src capacitor-electron://* 'unsafe-inline' devtools://* 'unsafe-eval' data:". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I've tried to add the following line to the index.html in the electron folder but still continue to get the same error:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">
```

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on the [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) documentation to have a better understanding. So, a general configuration that works for me was:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; connect-src * ;">
```

Comment: So I added something similar to 
export function setupContentSecurityPolicy(customScheme: string)
in the setup.ts file and that seemed to work when I use npx cap open @capacitor-community/electron to open it.
But when I run 'pm run electron:win' and package it and then run it from the release-builds I get the error again. 
Any ideas? Maybe I should have it as the meta tag instead. which file did you add that meta tag to? was it the index.html in the electron->app folder?

Comment: @JoeStarnes Yes, add it within the `<head>` tag of your `index.html` file.